# utility to find driver updates (Windows)

Tags: windows, update, drivers, utility

Is there a utility that helps (technically apt) end users to locate driver updates for their machine?

Personally, I use [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) to determine the hardware, then scour the manufacturers web sites. I am looking for soemthing a bit more streamlined to recommend to customers.

(we sell a performance-demanding external hardware, and most of the "strange problems" apparently can be solved with a driver update)

Comment: I've demoed a few and had some bad experiences. After installing the "newer" drivers, some of them were actually not right for my system and ended up causing so much grief I had to reformat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Driver Detective](http://www.drivershq.com/) actually works quiet well. It looks at your hardware and provides a list of URL's that provide the most update driver if the current one is out of date.

As Peter commented you do end up paying for it however I paid for it around 3 years ago and they have not hassled me for more money since then. Peter if you could say how much it costs that would be good as I have forgotten.

Comment: This looks very good, but they tell you the price only after you have provided an e-mail address (and even before that, there's no indication that it is a paid tool). I'd consider it for myself / us, but I wouldn#t recommend that to customers.

Answer (score 0):

if your using dell or HP machines then go to the vendors website.